# Slow update (primary key)

Tags: sql, performance, primary-key, sql-update

```
update auditdata set TATCallType='12',TATCallUnit='1' from auditdata auditdata 
        inner join Auditdata_sms_12 a_sns
        on auditdata.ID = a_sns.id
```

when I above query it takes more than 10 minutes to execute.

what wrong in this

`Auditdata.ID` is primary key..

if i run Update command is that also update the indexes???
is this reason of update getting is slow

Comment: Which DBMS? Roughly how large are the tables? Has this just started happening on an existing query, or is this a new query?

Comment: - What datatype is your primary key?
 - What indexes do you have on this table?

Comment: How big is the table? If this is 100,000,000 rows and it has to update every single row, it won't matter what indexes you have on it: It's going to take a while.

Comment: table is contain 1500000 rows 
& the temp table contain 3500000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comment, main table contains less rows than temp table.

Try using EXISTS clause (or in some sense, reduce the comparison to less number of rows (i.e. 1500000)

```
update auditdata set TATCallType='12',TATCallUnit='1' 
from auditdata auditdata 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT id from Auditdata_sms_12 a_sns WHERE a_sns.id = auditdata.ID)
```

The idea is to limit the comparisons.

EDIT: AuditdataSMS12 should have the index on ID to be able to get the row quickly. That is the table you are actually looking up for a given ID.

Comment: oh i really sorry..the main table contain 15000000
and temp table contain 3500000

Comment: hmmm. I still think you will need an index on temp table - because you are querying it & use of EXISTS clause should reduce the comparison when compared to inner join (if there is more than 1 row in temp table for a given ID in main table).

Comment: both Table ID column is primary and defined as cluster index is ok

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things at play here.

First, the SQL statement looks broken. The "FROM" clause in an update is designed to be used as a JOIN'd update. Since you're updating rows with hard-coded values, there's no need to do that.

Secondly, and more esoterically, if the indexes are all correct as you say they are, then perhaps you're dealing with a slow disk I/O for either the initial writes OR the transaction log area (undo in Oracle, logs in SQL Server, etc.).

As a sanity check I'd do two things. One, only update rows that do not already have the conditions set. Many DBMS products will happily perform physical disk I/O for a row that doesn't change (although many don't). Try it with the limit.

Two, apply the update in smaller batches. This can really help with log contention and with slower disks.

So, something like the following to initially try:

```
UPDATE auditdata 
   SET TATCallType = '12' 
     , TATCallUnit = '1' 
  FROM auditdata 
 WHERE TATCallType <> '12' 
   AND TATCallUnit <> '1'
   AND EXISTS( SELECT *
                 FROM Auditdata_sms_12 a_sns 
                WHERE a_sns.id = auditdata.ID )
```

If you want to do batches, in SQL Server it's pretty easy:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 2000

UPDATE ...

(run continually in a loop via T-SQL or by hand until @@ROWCOUNT = 0)

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
I realized after reading the initial query again that you were not updating the primary ID field, but 2 other data fields.  Please re-read the first statement of my response and comment accordingly.  Sorry.

Is there a clustered index defined on either field that you are updating?  There are advantages to clustered indexes ,I don't know them off hand, but they can cause large performance hits during updates.  My understanding is that an update to a clustered index can cause the entire index to have to recompile.  If you have a lot of data in the table this can definitely cause your problem.

Also, make sure there are no triggers on the table.  If there is a trigger that isn't acting right it can cause the same performance hit.

Comment: If you update the column in a clustered index, it will physically move the record (at least in SQL Server). This is why you don't insert a bunch of rows with interspersed PK values. Obviously, for many updates, this causes a lot of issues. However, the OP isn't updating the PK's here, so it won't be a clustered index.

Comment: Yes in my original table ID is primary key defined as clustered index
no trigger used

Comment: what should i do to fast the SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

How long does a simple select (eg

```
 select id from auditdata auditdata 
    inner join Auditdata_sms_12 a_sns
    on auditdata.ID = a_sns.id
```

) take and how many records does it find?

If Sql server has to read through all 5 million records , or update a million records and it does not have enough memory or fast enough hardware, then there may not much you with the query.

You probably need to monitor the Sql server hardware and also look at the Query Plan to see what bit takes up the time.